# WMS Layer in Folium

Tags: python, gis, folium, wms

I am trying to add a WMS layer into a folium map, but this layer requires additional parameters, which I am not 100% sure how to pass on.

It's from http://www.bom.gov.au/australia/meteye/, and the specific layer I am trying to bring in is IDZ73013.

When I try to add it in, it doesn't show on the map, probably because I need to specify the rest of the query params. See below example from a URL the website itself sends:

http://wvs3.bom.gov.au/mapcache/meteye?TRANSPARENT=true&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&layers=IDZ73013&TIMESTEP=0&BASETIME=202309050000&ISSUETIME=20230905003726&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=144,-54,162,-36&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256

I believe my issue is because I need to pass the BASETIME and TIMESTEP parameters to folium somehow, so it can get the right forecast image, but it doesn't seem to be working.

See below the code I got so far:

```
map_geo = folium.Map(location=[-25.9, 134.7], zoom_start=5)

wms = folium.raster_layers.WmsTileLayer(
    url = 'http://wvs3.bom.gov.au/mapcache/meteye?',
    layers = 'IDZ73013',
    transparent = True,
    control = True,
    overlay = True,
    show = True,
    name='rain',
    FORMAT="image/png",
    TIMESTEP='0',
    BASETIME='202309050600',
    SRS='EPSG:4326'
)
wms.add_to(map_geo)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(map_geo)

map_geo
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!